# find multi words match in makefile

Tags: makefile

Can anyone suggest how to achieve below in one line -

```
    ifeq ($(findstring city, $(TARGET_PRODUCT)), city)
    ..
    else ifeq ($(findstring man, $(TARGET_PRODUCT)), man)
    ..
    else ifeq ($(findstring zone, $(TARGET_PRODUCT)), zone)
    ..
    endif
```

Here city, man, zone are not complete words but partial pattern ,
for ex, velocity, Hitman, xzoneplace etc.

I find word match with filter option -

```
     ifneq (,$(filter $(OS),Darwin FreeBSD NetBSD))
         bar
     endif
```

But it seems not fit for partial match

Thanks

Comment: It will help if you can explain the motivation for the one-liner. Are all the '...' the same command ? If not, it will be very hard to understand line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.  You can write a recursive function that will do it, something like:

```
findany = $(if $1,$(or $(findstring $(firstword $1),$2),$(call findany,$(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1),$2)))

ifneq (,$(call findany,city man zone,$(TARGET_PRODUCT)))
```

The `findany` function returns the empty string if nothing matched (or else the first match, if that matters).

**ETA**

Actually this can be done much more simply: I guess I was feeling too recursive the other day.  You just need:

```
findany = $(foreach W,$1,$(findstring $W,$2))

ifneq (,$(call findany,city man zone,$(TARGET_PRODUCT)))
```

The first option above uses recursion to do the same thing.

Comment: MadScientist , can you please explain the findany method in steps ?

Answer (score 0):

The GNUmake library [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) has a function `glob-match` which may or may not be what you are looking for:

```
include ../gmtt/gmtt.mk

TARGET_PRODUCT := velocity
pattern := *city*
test_result = $(call glob-match,$(TARGET_PRODUCT),$(pattern))
$(info For pattern "$(pattern)" in string "$(TARGET_PRODUCT)" there was $(if $(test_result), a match: $(test_result), no match))

TARGET_PRODUCT := Hitman
pattern := *city*
test_result = $(call glob-match,$(TARGET_PRODUCT),$(pattern))
$(info For pattern "$(pattern)" in string "$(TARGET_PRODUCT)" there was $(if $(test_result), a match: $(test_result), no match))

pattern := *man*
test_result = $(call glob-match,$(TARGET_PRODUCT),$(pattern))
$(info For pattern "$(pattern)" in string "$(TARGET_PRODUCT)" there was $(if $(test_result), a match: $(test_result), no match))

TARGET_PRODUCT := xzoneplace
pattern := *city*
test_result = $(call glob-match,$(TARGET_PRODUCT),$(pattern))
$(info For pattern "$(pattern)" in string "$(TARGET_PRODUCT)" there was $(if $(test_result), a match: $(test_result), no match))

pattern := *zone*
test_result = $(call glob-match,$(TARGET_PRODUCT),$(pattern))
$(info For pattern "$(pattern)" in string "$(TARGET_PRODUCT)" there was $(if $(test_result), a match: $(test_result), no match))

pattern := *place*
test_result = $(call glob-match,$(TARGET_PRODUCT),$(pattern))
$(info For pattern "$(pattern)" in string "$(TARGET_PRODUCT)" there was $(if $(test_result), a match: $(test_result), no match))

pattern := *zone*place*
test_result = $(call glob-match,$(TARGET_PRODUCT),$(pattern))
$(info For pattern "$(pattern)" in string "$(TARGET_PRODUCT)" there was $(if $(test_result), a match: $(test_result), no match))
```

Output:

```
For pattern "*city*" in string "velocity" there was  a match:  velo city
For pattern "*city*" in string "Hitman" there was  no match
For pattern "*man*" in string "Hitman" there was  a match:  Hit man
For pattern "*city*" in string "xzoneplace" there was  no match
For pattern "*zone*" in string "xzoneplace" there was  a match:  x zone place
For pattern "*place*" in string "xzoneplace" there was  a match:  xzone place
For pattern "*zone*place*" in string "xzoneplace" there was  a match:  x zone place
```

Of course you don't need to use variables: `$(call glob-match,$(TARGET_PRODUCT),*some*funny*glob*)` works as well.